# Shared Pointer for parent and child

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

I have a problem with the initialization of some classes. Simplified code looks like:

```
class Base
{
    Base(int)
};

class BaseChild : public Base
{
};

class mainWindow
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Base> pBase;
    void init();
};

void mainWindow::init()
{
    this->pBase = boost::shared_ptr<Base>(new Base(12));
    this->pBase = boost::shared_ptr<Base>(new BaseChild(12));
}
```

So the problem is with initialization of BaseChild class which is child from Base class. What am I doing wrong? I thought that parentral class pointer can point on child class.

Generaly my program has to work in such way:

- When it starts, there is initialization of parental class (in above example: `this->pBase = boost::shared_ptr<Base>(new Base(12));`). This already works.
- In some case, when some flag change its value, pointer which point on parental class object should be change to point on child class object.

Comment: What exactly is "the problem" (besides `BaseChild` having no suitable constructor)?

Comment: It would help if you posted an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can see the relevant problems and not be distracted by extra fun ones.

Comment: I think that problem is mostly in constructor. Generaly I have to rewrite some part of program which was written by someone else. In main section program operate on shared pointer to Base class. I created subclass from Base and added some additional methods (also - created/refabricated virtual methods to change some functionality in already written methods in Base class). 
My problem is in sharing the pointer. I try to write code that in situation when some flag is occured, the shared pointer starts pointing on subclass, and when flag is disable - pointer back points in parental class.

Comment: you are missing a constructor in the derived class `BaseChild` that accepts an int as argument so your class is not complete since you write `new BaseChild(12)`

Comment: Just post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a constructor that takes `int` in `BaseChild`. Also constructor in `Base` is private, which makes it unusable outside `Base` class.
Try

```
class Base
{
public:
     Base(int);
};

class BaseChild : public Base
{
public:
    BaseChild(int);
};
```